# How can I use jquery for drag/drop

Tags: jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop script using an older version of jquery which relied on Interface.js which was what people used for drag and drop before jqueryUI was ever created.

I really need to convert/re-write my cript to use the newer versions of jquery though and the syntax is different now and it will not work with the older interface.js plugin

So does anyone know how I can make a jquery drag and drop that allows div's to drag and drop between 2 columns and then serailize the order into something like this

0:0|0:1|0:2|0:3|1:4|1:5|1:6|1:7

Notice the leading 0 is for the left column and the 1's are for the right column, the number after the | is the ID number of the div box

So with the above list of ID's there would be 2 columns with 4 divs in each of the 2 columns, I could then drag a div to any position and on drop it would update the serialized list so I an make an ajax call to a DB

Also if would really like to avoid using jqueryUI if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at

[Jquery Drag and Drop](http://web-design-dubai-uae.blogspot.com/2009/09/jquery-drag-and-drop.html)

May be this will help you...